# EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN on device

Tags: swift, crash

For some reason the code below, results in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN…` when run on a device. Simulator runs just fine so I guess it's directly related to the `ARM` in `EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN`.

```
struct Structure {
  var a: UInt8
  var b: UInt8
  var c: UInt8
}
enum Enum: Int {
  case One, Two, Three, Four
}
var x: [Enum: (Structure?, Structure?)] = [
  .One: (Structure(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3), nil)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's a Swift compiler bug and reported it under #20891471.

Though http://www.splinter.com.au/what-do-do-with-excarmdaalign-on-an-iphone-ap/ suggests that it's an `armv7` problem, I suppose Swift compiler could work around it.

For now, the easiest solution I could come up with (no idea how reliable it is) is:

```
struct Structure {
  var a: UInt8
  var b: UInt8
  var c: UInt8
  private let d: UInt8 = 0

  init(a: UInt8, b: UInt8, c: UInt8) {
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
  }
}
```

This modified `Structure` prevents the exception.